# Parsing multiple json objects from signle nsstring variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I know how to parse json object from `NSString` using `NSData` and `NSDictionary`, but I didn't find how to parse multiple json object if I get message like this:

```
{
"msg_type" : "fist_json",
"field" : "param"
}

{  "second_json_field": [   
    {      
         "name_picture": "0.png",
         "data_picture":"something"

    },
    {      
         "data_values": "something"    
    }  ]
}

{
"third_msg" : "hello"
}
```

Comment: Can't do it without some pre-processing.  Either isolate the individual pieces and parse separately or insert commas, slap on `[]`, and parse as an array.  (And give heck to whoever sent you the data that way.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid JSON, so you can't parse it. A JSON document is either a single array, or a single object (dictionary). Three objects are not valid JSON. You could put square brackets around everything, put commas in the right places, and parse it, getting an array back. Finding the places for the commas without writing a full-blown JSON parser is tricky.

If this is what the server gave you, ask the server people to fix their broken server. If your code for some reason combined three JSON messages into one, then don't do that.

Comment: Actually, the commas go between the `}` and the `{`, ignoring whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is not possible in one go. Your provided example text might look like [JSON](http://www.json.org/), but it isn't (valid).

I think the service that serves you this response should be 'fixed'.